# search data from database with multiple textbox using php

Tags: php, oracle

search with multiple textbox using php

I am try this code for search with multiple textbox using php and i am using orcle database but this code is not work. and any one let me know what is the problem why this code not search with multiple text box field and also i have getting  error Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00920: invalid relational operator in

plz check .....my code..

```
  <form action="Optr_Search.php" method="get">
     <table width="500" border="0" align="center">    
                    <tr>
                    <td width="203"><div align="right"><strong>Operator ID:</strong>    

             </div></td>
                    <td width="148"><input type="text" name="OPRID" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right"><strong>Operator Name:</strong></div></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="OPRDEFNDESC" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right"><strong>Person ID:</strong></div></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="EMPLID" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><div align="right"><strong>Email ID:</strong></div></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="EMAILID" /></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td colspan="2"> 
                  <div align ="center">
                    </br>
   <input type="submit" align ="middle"value="Search" name ="submit" />
                  </div>
                  </td>

            </tr>
         </table>  
         </form>            


  <?php
  $ora_conn = oci_connect('system','oracle','//localhost/XE'); 
  if(!$ora_conn)
   {
  $m = oci_error();
  echo $m['message'], "\n"; 
   exit; 
   } 
   else 
    { 
    print "You are connected to the database!<br/>"; 
     }


   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
  $optid = $_POST['OPRID'];
  $optdec = $_POST['OPRDEFNDESC'];
  $empid = $_POST['EMPLID'];
  $empmail = $_POST['EMAILID'];

  $query = "SELECT * FROM OPERATOR WHERE 1";
  if(isset($optid) && $optid != '') {
  $query .= " And OPRID Like'%$optid%'";
  }
   if(isset($optdec) && $optdec != '') {
   $query .= " OR OPRDEFNDESC Like'%$optdec%'";
   }
   if(isset($empid) && $empid != '') {
  $query .= " OR EMPLID Like '%$empid%'";
}
if(isset($empmail) && $empmail != '') {
 $query .= " OR EMAILID Like '%$empmail%'";
}

     $objParse = oci_parse($ora_conn,$query);
  $objResult = oci_execute ($objParse, OCI_DEFAULT);   

 ?> 

  <table width="500" border="1" align="center">  
  <tr>  
  <th width="98"> <div align="center">Operator ID</div></th>  
  <th width="98"> <div align="center">Operator Name</div></th>  
  <th width="98"> <div align="center">Person ID</div></th>  
  <th width="98"> <div align="center">Email ID</div></th>   
  <th width="98"> <div align="center">Edit</div></th>   
   </tr> 

    <?php 
  if(oci_execute($objParse,OCI_DEFAULT)){
  while($objResult = oci_fetch_array($objParse, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC)) 
   {    
     ?>    
 <tr>  
 <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["OPRID"];?></div></td>  
 <td><?=$objResult["OPRDEFNDESC"];?></td>  
 <td><?=$objResult["EMPLID"];?></td>  
 <td><div align="center"><?=$objResult["EMAILID"];?></div></td> 
  <td align="center"><a  href="Optr_Edit.php?OprID=<?=$objResult["OPRID"];?>">Edit</a>   
  </td> 
  </tr>  
  <?  
   }  
    ?>  
    </table>  
      <?  
    oci_free_statement($objParse);
     oci_close($ora_conn); 
     } 

     ?>
```

Comment: You can't use `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` because of `method="get"` change it to `method="post"` and try again.

Comment: ok i am change it to method="post" but when i am fill of the form and click on submit then print SELECT * FROM OPERATOR WHERE 1 And OPRID Like'%praveen%' on the o/p page,,...

Comment: i have use echo $query; exit;
in my code now i am remove this from codeing..ok

Comment: Sorry, am having a hard time understanding what you said. This line seems to be missing something `SELECT * FROM OPERATOR WHERE 1` usually you want to do something like `SELECT * FROM OPERATOR WHERE id='".$id."; LIMIT 1`

Comment: can u explain what sql query i am use...here

Comment: can we use this type,,,...$query ="SELECT  * FROM OPERATOR WHERE(OPRID LIKE '%".$_GET["OPRID"]."%'  
            or OPRDEFNDESC LIKE '%".$_GET["OPRDEFNDESC"]."%' or EMPLID LIKE '%".$_GET["EMPLID"]."%'
   or EMAILID LIKE '%".$_GET["EMAILID"]."%') ";

Comment: I would imagine you could. Try it and see.

Comment: but i have getting error ..

Comment: Sorry I can't help you any further. I suggest you Google and consult the SQL manual. It's the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing ands and ors in SQL and this is not a good idea.  If you set them all to or, you will have an issue because where 1 will always be true.  I would make your or conditional on the where clause not being empty.